# Suggestion on a source to Landau and Ginzburg theory

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, phase-transition, superconductivity

I am trying to learn by myself on the [Landau-Ginzburg theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ginzburg%E2%80%93Landau_theory) for phase transition , I have seen few lectures of MIT on their youtube channels but I still not sure I understood the Idea here. I would like for suggestion on academic articles and Lecture notes about that topic (I am familiar with the mean field approximation , Ising model and critical exponents already).

Comment: Presumably the lectures you saw on youtube are from Kardar -- a text reference for these lecture videos is Kardar's [Statistical Physics of Fields](https://www.amazon.com/Statistical-Physics-Fields-Mehran-Kardar-dp-052187341X/dp/052187341X/ref=mt_other?_encoding=UTF8&me=&qid=).

Comment: @Zack in this book the only information presented is the Landau ginzburg hamiltonian, neither motivation or introduction.

Comment: I disagree that no motivation or introduction is given -- certainly, no _derivation_ is given, but that's kind of the point of Landau-Ginzburg theory: it's a phenomenological approach to understanding universal properties near a critical point. But if you'd like a less terse reference, my personal favorite is Goldenfeld's [Lectures on Phase Transitions and the Renormalization Group](https://www.amazon.com/Lectures-Transitions-Renormalization-Frontiers-Physics/dp/0201554097).

Comment: For a fast/good review see Chapter 13 of this book: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.3575

Comment: @SG8 thank you very much, as far as I understood G-L theory is general approach to describe phase transition wich is found really usefull to describe supercondctivity. but I can't find the derivation of the $G-L$ theory. is there exist one? or is it just an assumption I should  accept as it is. (specific on page 243 eq 13.62